# Google playstore app Recent Query

Tags: android

Using this code, I am able to clear the recent query in the google playstore app:

```
SearchRecentSuggestions query = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this, "com.google.android.finsky.RecentSuggestionsProvider", 1);    
query.clearHistory();
```

However, how can I use the recent query? (for example: showing the first query in a TextView)

Comment: How you fixed the SecurityException? java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.finsky.providers.RecentSuggestionsProvider

Answer (score 0):

By default, the query is appended as the last segment of the uri parameter (a Uri object). To retrieve the query text in this case, simply use getLastPathSegment(). For example:

String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase();

For example, here's how you might form the android:searchSuggestSelection attribute to create a full-text search statement:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.MyCustomSuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestSelection="word MATCH ?">
</searchable>
```

`
With this configuration, your query() method delivers the selection parameter as "word MATCH ?" and the selectionArgs parameter as the search query. When you pass these to an SQLite query() method, as their respective arguments, they are synthesized together (the question mark is replaced with the query text). If you chose to receive suggestion queries this way and need to add wildcards to the query text, append (and/or prefix) them to the selectionArgs parameter, because this value is wrapped in quotes and inserted in place of the question mark.

Another new attribute in the example above is android:searchSuggestIntentAction, which defines the intent action sent with each intent when the user selects a suggestion. It is discussed further in the section about Declaring an Intent for Suggestions.

Comment: how can I access the query that way?

Comment: ` // Get the intent, //verify the action and get the query Intent intent = getIntent(); 
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) { String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY); doMySearch(query); } `

Comment: I can't grasp the idea. What I want is instead of clearing the query, how can I use its data. Like listing them or putting them in textview.